# Adding CALayer with image content on top of other CALayer.

Tags: ios, video, camera, uiimage, calayer

i am having problem with adding image on CALayer on top of other CALayer. I am getting the image added but its blured and not crispy clear. Can someone help me to get some solution? Here is my Code.

```
CALayer *imageHolderLayer = [CALayer layer];
imageHolderLayer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
imageHolderLayer.contents = (id)self.feedImage.CGImage;
imageHolderLayer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, 88, 88);
imageHolderLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 50, 88, 88);
imageHolderLayer.cornerRadius = 88/2;
imageHolderLayer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
imageHolderLayer.borderWidth = 3.0;
[imageHolderLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
imageHolderLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
imageHolderLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;

CGSize videoSize = [videoAsset naturalSize];
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width,videoSize.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:shadowLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:logoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:titleLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:imageHolderLayer];
```

Comment: Why are you saying `shouldRasterize`?

Comment: @matt i tried without it and its the same.

Comment: Okay, let me ask this: do you get the same "not crispy clear" result if you just show _one_ layer instead of both? Let's try to remove any irrelevant complications. You are adding a lot of layers, but is the problem merely the `contents` of the `imageHolderLayer`, without the other layers?

Comment: @matt i have tried to remove all the layer just left the VideoLayer and the ImageholderLayer and its still not crispy clear.

Comment: So it sounds like it might just be an effect of scaling `self.feedImage.CGImage` down to 88 by 88? How big was it originally?

Comment: Or is it caused by the video layer? What is that? You are layering in front of video???

Comment: @matt the real image is 300x300 and the litle one is 88x88 also i am getting the video from URL path and edit it with layers.

Comment: "the real image is 300x300 and the litle one is 88x88" So maybe that's the problem. How is it supposed to show a 300x300 image in an 88x88 space "crisply"? It has to scale down somehow, so clearly we will lose pixels and clarity.

Comment: Yea ill try to scale it.

Comment: @matt i have scaled it to CGSize(88,88) but still getting it not clear.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you expect. Scaling will always lose some detail. That is what scaling _is_. You are throwing away pixels.